# Is it possible to simplify $\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)\ \Gamma\left(\frac{7}{15}\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, special-functions, closed-form, gamma-function

Is it possible to simplify this expression?
$$\frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)\ \Gamma\left(\frac{7}{15}\right)}$$
Is there a systematic way to check ratios of Gamma-functions like this for simplification possibility?

Comment: Thanks to se.math user A. Walker, I recently became aware of the paper [Expressions for the values of the Gamma Function](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf), which gives values for $\Gamma(a/b)$ whenever $b$ divides 120.

Comment: See a lot of related material at MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7616

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Amazingly, this can be greatly simplified.  I'll state the result first:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{15}\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{3^{1/10} 2^{6/5} \sqrt{\pi}}$$

The result follows first from a version of [Gauss's multiplication formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5#iii):

$$\displaystyle\Gamma(3 z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} 3^{3 z-1/2} \Gamma(z) \Gamma\left(z+\frac13\right) \Gamma\left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

or, with $z=2/15$:

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{15}\right) = 2 \pi \,3^{1/10} \frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}$$

Now use the duplication formula

$$\Gamma(2 z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\, 2^{2 z-1}  \Gamma(z) \Gamma\left(z+\frac12\right)$$

or, with $z=2/5$:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \, 2^{1/5}}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)}$$

Putting this all together, we get

$$\frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)}{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{15}\right)} = \frac{\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi^3} \, 2^{6/5} \, 3^{1/10}}$$

And now, we may use the [reflection formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5#ii):

$$\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}$$

With $z=1/10$, and noting that

$$\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}+1}$$

the stated result follows.  This has been verified numerically in [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BGamma%5B1/10%5D/%28Gamma%5B2/15%5D%20Gamma%5B7/15%5D%29,%28Sqrt%5B5%5D%2b1%29/%283%5E%281/10%29%202%5E%286/5%29%20Sqrt%5BPi%5D%29%7D//N).

Comment: Wonderful! Wouldn't it look even better as
$$\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt[10]{12288}\sqrt{\pi}}$$?

Maybe not...

Comment: Why are you so good at making answers @RonGordon ? Easy +1 from me!

Comment: The last line is FALSE:

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right) \neq \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: @KimPeek: Why...because you say so?  I say it is true.  I have analysis and numerics on my side.  Prove me wrong.

Comment: $$\sin\left(\pi/10\right) = 0.587 \ldots$$

$$\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{5}} = 0.309\ldots $$

Comment: @KimPeek: Your value of $\sin{(\pi/10)}$ is incorrect.

Comment: @KimPeek http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28pi%2F10%29

Comment: uhm... ok I did it with my calculator and I repeated it with wolfram Alpha and they gave me two different results.. I think my calculator has some bug lol! Forgive me!

Comment: lol this is SOOO strange!! I tried to compute

$$\sqrt{5}$$

with my calculator and it gives me

$$\sqrt{5} = 1.982283324\ldots$$

There is definitely something wrong....

Comment: @KimPeek: You need to develop instincts for this stuff rather than rely on a calculator.  Know that, when $x$ is small, $\sin{x} \approx x$ in radians.  Thus it should be plain that when $x = \pi/10$, $x$ and $\sin{x}$ should not be that far off.

Comment: You're right :/ I apologize again!!

Comment: Anyway, this is awesome because then we can state that

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right) = \frac{1}{2\phi_0}$$

Where $\phi_0$ is the golden ratio!! *_*

Comment: Nice solution. I particular like that software like Mathematica is not able to simplify it directly. The expression can also be written $\frac{\phi }{\sqrt[10]{12}\sqrt{\pi}}$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: @Winther: lots of ways to express, but the important thing is that we can write this horrific-looking beast in terms of things a pocket calculator can produce.