# Simplification of a combination of 6 values of the gamma function

Tags: analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

I'm trying to simplify this combination of gamma functions:
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{12}{25}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{8}{25}\right)}$$
I tried to apply [Gauss's multiplication formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function-Legendre_function), as it was done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406219/79200), but without any success. It is possible to simplify this expression at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [Gauss Multiplication Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function-Legendre_function), which is proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1123116),
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac2{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{12}{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{17}{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{22}{25}\right)=4\pi^25^{1/10}\Gamma\left(\frac25\right)
$$
Using the [Euler Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#Known_formula), proven at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216),
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac3{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{22}{25}\right)=\frac\pi{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{25}\right)}
$$
and
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac8{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{17}{25}\right)=\frac\pi{\sin\left(\frac{8\pi}{25}\right)}
$$
Putting these together, we get
$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac2{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{12}{25}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac25\right)\Gamma\left(\frac3{25}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac8{25}\right)}=4\cdot5^{1/10}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{25}\right)\sin\left(\frac{8\pi}{25}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Maple, I get

$$
{\frac {{5}^{1/10} \left( 2\,\cos \left( {\frac {8\,\pi }{25}}
 \right) +2\,\cos \left( {\frac {4\,\pi }{25}} \right) +1 \right) }{
2\;\cos \left( {\frac {6\,\pi }{25}} \right) +2\;\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{5} \right) 
}}
$$